# Quartz.net pausing between concurrent jobs

Tags: c#, quartz.net

I have a job that uploads some data to an ftp,and it needs to end before it starts again.So as a result I have used a DisallowConcurrentExecution attribute with the class.Now my problem is when the job is finished it doesn't wait for a another x seconds until it starts again.For example:

```
            ISchedulerFactory schedFact = new StdSchedulerFactory();


        IScheduler sched = schedFact.GetScheduler();
        sched.Start();



        IJobDetail job = JobBuilder.Create<HelloJob>()
            .WithIdentity("myJob", "group1")
            .Build();

        ITrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
          .WithIdentity("myTrigger", "group1")
          .StartNow()
          .WithSimpleSchedule(x => x
              .WithIntervalInSeconds(5)
              .RepeatForever()
              .WithMisfireHandlingInstructionNextWithRemainingCount())
          .Build();

        sched.ScheduleJob(job, trigger);





    }}


[DisallowConcurrentExecution]
public class HelloJob : IJob
{
    public void Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("start");
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
        Console.WriteLine("end");


    }
}
```

This job starts,does something for 5 secs and ends.However quartz starts the next job immediately since it has counted 5 seconds as the the job started.
So how can I achieve 
**start job - do something for 5 secs - end - wait for 5 secs - start again- ...** 
behavior with quartz.net?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a chain of jobs, instead of a forever repeating job. At the end of the execution of your job, schedule it to execute in 5 seconds.